# Taking input from text field and fetching data from database using ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, user-input

I have a input text field and when user give input in text field, it should fetch the data from database with respect to user-input

```
<p><input type="text" name="ajax" id="ajaxtest1" ></p>



<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

$("#ajaxtest1").blur(function(){
    var dt=$(this).val();
 $.post("test.php", { purchase_product:dt});


 <?php
   $purchase_product = $_POST['purchase_product'];
   $sql="SELECT SUM(purchase_quantity) as quantity FROM purchase WHERE purchase_product = '".mysql_real_escape_string($purchase_product)."'";
    $f=$database->query($sql);
    $found=$database->fetch_array($f);

    print_r($found);
    ?>

});
     });
     </script>
```

My query is correct(I have tested by given exact value in .mysql_real_escape_string(myvale or string).) it is working fine.But result I am getting in above code for user input is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [quantity] => 
)
```

Help me out

Comment: Is your database have result set for user input??

Answer (score 0):

try adding a cakkback function to your ajax request.
Allow me to paste just the specific alteration on your code.

```
 $.post("test.php", 
  { purchase_product:dt},
   function(data){ $('selector').html(data);}
   );
```

the selector in this case will be the html element that you want to show the result

Comment: It won't work on same files.I have give my php query in different file .it works on two different files